# Biduals generated by projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

This question is motivated by a similar question recently posed at MO:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122091/masas-in-second-duals-of-banach-algebras

In this setting, let $B$ be a Banach algebra *generated by projections*, meaning that the span of all idempotents in $B$ is norm dense. Is the second dual of $B$ endowed with either Arens product generated by projections?

Comment: You are likely to get a better answer back at mathoverflow